# How do I fill my vector file with color?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, fill

First of all, I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I've been searching and trying for the past 2 hours without any luck. I'm only getting started with Illustrator, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I purchased this file and am trying to colorise it (fill it with color).

I found how to change the border color of it, but I can't find a way to fill the actual inside of the image. I found a way but it's extremely complicated ..if I change the background image of the entire file and move it behind, so I assume the background that I am trying to fill is currently transparent.

How would I do this? I'm totally lost :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the live paint tool.

[image]

Select your object and choose Object>Live Paint>Make

[image]

Choose the Live Paint Bucket tool

[image]

Fill with your selected color

You can later expand the object if you need to edit it further.

Comment: Wooohooo, that worked perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You could double click on the bird, then you'll 'isolate' that shape. Then click the inside shape of the bird and delete it. That'll get rid of the faux border effect on it and allow you to fill the entire bird with whatever you want.

If you want to keep the faux border effect and still be able to fill inside it I'd still delete the inside shape, but apply an inside stroke to the same width.